# Ошибка при подключении БД в VIsual Studio

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, visual-studio

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имя сервера правильно ввожу, но выдаёт такую ошибку, может дело в самом SQL. Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Покажите строку соединения. / Зачем метка `mysql`? Вы с какой именно СУБД работаете?

Comment: MySql и Sql Server - это две **разные** СУБД. Определитесь, с какой именно вы работаете. И для подключения используйте строку соединения именно для конкретной СУБД.